# How to import an array of all the non-blank cells of a sheet (for matrix multiplication)?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, matrix-multiplication, array-formulas

I've got a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QSQWZ8rMo6jFGYbsaH6yNRfFfXWSHSASovUJoKN5MuU/edit?usp=sharing) for calculating the nutrition data for each meal I eat. One sheet ("ingredients") contains  a matrix of nutrition data for each ingredient. Another sheet ("recipes") contains a matrix of servings of each ingredient for each meal. In my "meal nutrition data" sheet, I want to multiply those matrices to get the nutrition data for each recipe.

I can do this for the definite number of ingredients and recipes that I currently have: `=mmult(ingredients!B5:AF39,recipes!B2:G32)`, but if I add recipes or ingredients, I want it to automatically update, so I don't want that formula to be hardcoded. Since matrices need a value in all cells to multiply and since the constraint NxP * PxM (num rows x num columns) must hold, I need to import an array of all of the non-blank cells of each sheet into the `MMULT()` formula.

My current attempt `=mmult(query(ingredients!B5:FN39,"select * where Col1 is not null",0),query(recipes!B2:G32,"select * where Col1 is not null",0))` is not working. It throws the error: "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col1".

I can't figure out what should replace the word "Col1", or if my formula is an efficient way of achieving these results.

I also tried the `filter()` function but it cannot work with an array.

#### file.csv

```py
ingredient,"Great Value Golden Sweet Whole Kernel Corn, 15 oz","Great Value White Kidney Beans Cannellini Beans, 15.5 oz","Organic Great Value Garbanzo Beans Chick Peas, 15 oz","Great Value Sweet Peas, 15 oz",Great Value Chunk Light Tuna in Water 12 oz. Can,"Great Value Chunk Light Tuna in Water, 5 oz","Great Value Sardines in Water, 3.75 oz","Great Value 100% Whole Wheat Bread, Round Top, 20 oz","Great Value Wheat Sandwich Bread, 20 oz",Unsalted Roasted Peanuts,"Tyson® Fully Cooked Chicken Patties, 59.2 oz. (Frozen)","Butterball All Natural 90%/10% Lean Ground Turkey, 1 lb.",Sweet Potato,Potato,"Country Crock Original Butter Spread, 15 oz",Great Value Extra Virgin Olive Oil 101 oz,Romaine Lettuce,Great Value Teriyaki Sauce 15 oz,Great Value Soy Sauce 15 oz,Great Value Ketchup 64 oz,Great Value Reduced Fat Mayo with Olive Oil 30 oz,Kroger Ranch Dressin 16 oz,"Great Value Light Creamy Caesar Dressing, 16 oz",Large Egg,"Great Value Diced Tomatoes In Tomato Juice, 28 Oz",Green Bell Pepper,Cucumber,"Great Value Italian Style Bread Crumbs, 15 oz","Great Value Finely Shredded Parmesan Cheese, 6 oz","Great Value Frozen Rising Crust Supreme Pizza, 30.7 oz",Nature Valley Chocolate Pretzel Nut Chewy Granola Bars,Great Value Long Grain Enriched Rice,Broccoli Stir-Fry,Poke Marinade and Sauce ,Great Value Blueberries,Great Value Frozen Mango Chunks,Great Value Frozen Chopped Spinach,Bananas,Blue Diamond Unsweetened Original Almond Milk,Tropicana 100% Orange Juice (some pulp),Kroger 100% Pineapple Juice (unsweetened),Zucchini,Simple Truth Organic Tofu Extra Firm,"Classico Signature Recipes Traditional Basil Pesto Sauce and Spread, 8.1 oz Jar","Frozen Cooked Medium Peeled & Deveined Tail-On Shrimp, 12 oz"
ingredient type,starchy vegetable,bean,bean,vegetable,protein,protein,protein,grain,grain,snack,protein,protein,starchy vegetable,starchy vegetable,fat,fat,vegetable,sauce,sauce,sauce,sauce,sauce,sauce,protein,vegetable,vegetable,vegetable,grain,dairy,meal,snack,carb,vegetable,sauce,fruit,fruit,vegetable,fruit,dairy,fruit,fruit,vegetable,protein,sauce,protein
servings per container,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3,8,1,22,22,6,22,4,1,1,,,,,,,,,,,7,1,1,,,6,,50,7,16,3,10,4,,8,6,8,,0,4,4
serving size,1/2 cup,1/2 cup,1/2 cup,1/2 cup,3 oz,2 oz,1 can,1 slice,1 slice,1 oz,1 patty,4 oz,1 medium potato (114 g),1 medium potato (148 g),1 tbsp,1tbsp,2 cups (94g),1 tbsp,1 tbsp,1 tbsp,1 tbsp,2 tbsp,2 tbsp,1 egg,1/2 cup,1 pepper (100 g),1 cucumber (104g),1/3 cup,1/3 cup,1/6 pizza,1,1/4 cup,1 cup,1 tbsp,1 cup,1 cup,1 cup,1 banana,1 cup,8 fl oz,8 fl oz,1 zucchini,1 pack,1/4 cup,11
calories,45,110,110,60,80,45,100,60,70,170,200,190,103,110,50,120,15,15,5,20,50,140,70,70,25,20,16,110,110,330,150,160,30,50,100,130,35,105,30,110,120,33,270,240,100
total fat (g),0.5,0,2,0,0.5,0.5,4.5,0.5,1,15,13,11,0,0,6,14,0,0,0,0,6,14,6,5,0,0,0,1.5,7,12,5,0,0,0,1.5,0.5,0.5,0.4,2.5,0,0,0.6,13.5,24,1.5
saturated fat (g),0,0,0,0,0,0,1.5,0,0,2,3,2.5,0,0,1.5,2,0,0,0,0,1,2.5,1,1.5,0,0,0,0,4,4.5,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0.2,1.5,4.5,0.5
trans fat (g),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0,0,0
polyunsaturated fat (g),0,0,0,0,0,0,1.5,0,0,0,4.5,0,0,0,2.5,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,3.5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0
monounsaturated fat (g),0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1.5,0,1.5,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.5,0,0,0,0,0,0
cholesterol (mg),0,0,0,0,35,20,75,0,0,0,35,80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,0,185,0,0,0,0,20,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,180
sodium (mg),200,270,120,300,270,180,300,110,135,0,400,80,41,0,100,0,10,600,900,160,110,260,560,70,180,3,2,420,340,810,110,0,20,710,0,0,80,1,170,0,35,16,45,590,710
total carbohydrates (g),9,20,18,11,0,0,0,11,13,5,10,0,24,26,0,0,3,3,1,5,1,2,3,0,5,5,4,65,1,42,24,36,7,11,24,29,4,27,1,26,30,6,9,5,2
dietary fiber (g),1,6,4,3,0,0,0,2,1,3,0,0,4,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,21,0,2,1,1,2,0,6,3,3,3.1,1,0,1,2,3,1,0
total sugars (g),2,1,3,5,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,7,1,0,0,1,2,0,4,0,1,2,0,3,2,2,1,0,4,9,0,2,9,17,27,0,14,0,22,26,4.9,3,0,0
added sugars (g),0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,13,8,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
protein (g),1,7,6,3,18,0,16,4,2,8,9,20,2,3,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,6,1,1,0,4,10,0,2,3,2,1,0,1,3,1.3,1,2,0,2.4,27,3,20
potassium (mg),125,440,210,133,210,110,0,0,30,210,0,0,0,620,0,0,232,0,0,0,0,0,0,70,93,0,152,0,0,0,0,50,200,55,130,340,245,422,160,450,260,0,282,0,0
vitamin A (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,18,0,0,0,0,0,"3,942",0,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,0,63,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,150,0,0,63,0,225,36
calcium (mg),14,50,30,17,0,0,325,50,20,30,0,104,52,20,0,0,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,0,13,16,78,325,195,0,10,29,0,0,40,124,0,450,20,0,39,390,195,104
vitamin D (mcg),0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
vitamin C (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11.1,27,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,120,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,101,0,15.3,0,90,72,52,0,7.2,0
iron (mg),0,2.2,1.2,1,1.2,0.6,1.7,0.8,1,1,0.4,1.8,0.7,1.1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.9,0,0.4,2,1.1,0,2.7,0.9,1.9,1,0,0,0,1.6,0.2,0.7,0,0,0.36,4.32,1.08,0.36
vitamin b-6 (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0.9,0,0,0
magnesium (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,15,0,0,33.6,0,0,0
thiamine (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
riboflavin (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
niacin (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
folate (mcg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,174,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
vitamin k (mcg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
vitamin b-12 (mcg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
zinc (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
vitamin e (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7.5,0,0,0,0,0,0
biotin (mcg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
pantothenic acid (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
phosphorus (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0
iodine (mcg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
selenium (mcg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
choline (mg),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,150,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(
 INDIRECT("ingredients!B5:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(ingredients!A5:A)+4, 
 MAX(IF(ingredients!1:1="",,COLUMN(ingredients!1:1))))), 
 INDIRECT("recipes!B2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(recipes!A2:A)+1, 
 MAX(IF(recipes!1:1="",,COLUMN(recipes!1:1)))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow, amazing. I really appreciate that. So, indirect() helps you count the filled rows and columns and uses that to explicitly call the array. That's beautiful, I've never done anything like that. The world doesn't deserve people like you, thank you!